# What does the media="" attribute in the stylesheet HTML definition refer to?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm sure some of you have seen the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="styles.css" media="screen,projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" src="styles.css" media="print" />
```

Or whatever else...

But what does the media attribute actually do? I've created several websites and I have never used the media attributes when linking stylesheets. Is that a mistake?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) can explain it best.

The media types are about what media is to be used to view the page.

If someone is printing the page, the `print` media CSS is used. This is useful in many cases - if your site is white text on black background, the `print` CSS can be the opposite so ink is not wasted.

Screen is what you would normally think about - the computer screen, how most people will see the site.

Projection - if you want to have a larger font when projecting the website.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Both of your answers are correct, except this is more collaborative. I will mark it correct as soon as I am able to. Thanks again.

Comment: @Amit -collaborative? How so?

Comment: @Oded - You described what each Screen/Projection/Print are used for (which I didn't know). BTW - Love the country you were born in :)

Comment: @Amit - you mean descriptive... collaborative means working together with others... שיהיה לך שבוע טוב

Comment: @Amit - didn't think it was you. Just wondering about the random downvote, and would like to know why it happened.

Answer (score 5):

It defines the media-type of the stylesheet. Or the application of a given stylesheet, if you will.

If you include a stylesheet with the media property to "print"; the rules in that stylesheet will only affect a page when it gets printed out. If you set the media property to "screen"; the rules in the stylesheet won't affect the print-out of the page, but will affect the page when viewed in a browser.

If you define the media property as being "screen, print"; rules in the stylesheet will affect both the print-out of the page and how it looks in a browser.

Here's [a link to the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) at W3C (the organization which defines the standards for CSS).

Answer (score 1):

These are media types, which allow you to target a style sheet to a specific medium.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html. This functionality has been extended with *media queries*: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/.